# populate Python list passed as argument to C function

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, python-c-api

I am writing a Python extension using C. How can I populate an empty list inside C when the list is passed as an argument and the C function does not return the list but a different `PyObject*`.

```
b=[]
a = c.populate(data=b)
print b
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`PyList_Append()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#PyList_Append) to add individual elements to an existing Python `list` object:

> Append the object *item* at the end of list *list*. Return `0` if successful; return `-1` and set an exception if unsuccessful. Analogous to `list.append(item)`.

Alternatively, use [`PyList_SetSlice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#PyList_SetSlice) to extend the list with items from another `list` object:

> Set the slice of *list* between *low* and *high* to the contents of *itemlist*. Analogous to `list[low:high] = itemlist`. The *itemlist* may be *NULL*, indicating the assignment of an empty list (slice deletion). Return `0` on success, `-1` on failure. Negative indices, as when slicing from Python, are not supported.

Comment: Thank you very much Martijn. I tried and like the PyList_Append() solution you advised to me. Do you know how can I set the size of the list to empty in C code (not in Python side) so that if the c.populate is inside a Python loop the b buffer would not grow bigger and bigger. Thanks again.

Comment: Use `PyList_SetSlice()` with `itemlist` set to `NULL`, `low` set to `0` and `high` set to `Py_SIZE` of the list.

Comment: Sorry I might have missed your PyList_SetSlice() recommendation. I tried it and it worked brilliantly for my purpose. Thank you very much Martijn.